# Eclipse Data Tools Project - SQL Query Parser

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, parsing

Just recently discovered the SQL Query Parser classes in the DTP project, and it looks like a great (and unique) project.

My problem is that I need to analyze and see if I can merge some pretty hairy SQL fragments that are used in a big system. I need a smart and capable parser so I can perform an accurate analysis and determine if I can join some of these fragments together to improve performance. I've already figured the analysis I need to perform; however, the parser as-is is not able to parse these fragments, because they use specific db2 OLAP functions (`over()`, `partition by`, etc.) so I need to include the db2 plugins to my code.

How is this done? I haven't been able to find the classes (`org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.parsers.sql.query.db2.*`) anywhere, and I also have no idea how to register them (I'm trying to do it manually, but of course it cannot find the appropriate class.)

This is what I'm currently doing, which I know is wrong, but I haven't found documentation about it:

```
SQLQueryParserManagerProvider provider = SQLQueryParserManagerProvider
        .getInstance();

provider.registerParserManager(
        "org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.parsers.sql.query.db2",
        "DB2 UDB", null, null);

SQLQueryParserManager parserManager = SQLQueryParserManagerProvider
        .getInstance().getParserManager("DB2 UDB", null);
```

**Can you please point out how to get the adequate parser for parsing DB2?**

*Edit*: Probably the right question is, how can I make sure the db2 specific provider is correctly registered? what's the right class name?

Comment: How do you in fact know there is a DB2-compatible parser?  A real problem with most language parsers is that they are in fact for a very specific dialect of such langauge, and yet there are many dialects produced by the various suppliers (e.g., SQL2011 [standard], PL/SQL 8/9/10/11, MySQL, TSQL, DB2, all of them different).  If somebody hasn't specifically addressed the DB2 dialect ("I can't find classes ....db2.*") then they may simply not exist.

Comment: Well, it's [right there in the documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/datatools/project_sqldevtools/sqltools_doc/SQL%20Query%20Parser%20User%20documentation.htm), and IBM Data Studio supposedly uses it.

Comment: Still looking at this - the closest hierarchy to what the documentation shows is `org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.ibm.db2` but still no luck

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the project called SQLWorkBench/J sources. They have db-specific SQL parsing capabilities.

Comment: Looks like a nice project. It shows some features that hint that their parser is quite powerful (their 'src/sql' directory seems promising.) Alas, I don't have db2 drivers in my PC and it requires a profile, and db2 wasn't in the list. I'll keep investigating, thought.